# Prove that $2^{n+100} = O(2^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Having trouble proving this for Big Oh. just dont know where to start with this one.

I learn the basics over big oh notation so for this one, would i have so if $s(n) = 2^{n+100}$ and $a(n) = 2^n$ , then would i have to use the limit as $n \rightarrow\infty$ that $\frac{s(n)}{a(n)}=0$?

Comment: $2^{n+100}=2^n\times2^{100}$.

Comment: is it really that simple? is the method to solving this just to seperate s(n) and make it have a(n) included in it?

Comment: Sometimes it is that simple! You can directly apply the def. of Big Oh notation to prove this one.